# Do not close fancybox then parent site reloads

Tags: fancybox

My website with a data table releaods every 30 seconds to receive new data from a database.

The problem now is, if a fancybox is open (a chart is shown) and the parent site reloads, my fancybox with the chart closes.

How can I prevent this behavior? Meaning parent site reloads and receives new data and the opened fancybox (chart) still stays in the foreground till I close it.

Answer (score 0):

Proper solution would be not to reload the page, but use ajax to get fresh data. It is technically impossible to keep modal open while page refresh. You could open fancybox after each refresh, but it would not be smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this behavior by using the JavaScript method `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function() {location.reload();},30*1000);
```

instead of

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

During reloading, the site is flashing, but the fancybox remains. It works for me.